# Can one Observable() handle the Subscribe for two situations?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unirx

I'm applying reactive programming to the Unity3D project.

Entering a character in InputField enables the button and disables it if there are no characters.
Can this logic be processed in one stream using UniRx.Observable?

```
inputID.OnValueChangedAsObservable()
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false)
            .Subscribe(_ => buttonLogin.gameObject.SetActive(true));

inputID.OnValueChangedAsObservable()
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == true)
            .Subscribe(_ => buttonLogin.gameObject.SetActive(false));
```

Can combine these two logics into one logic?

Please reply. Thank you.

Comment: No expert but can't you simply do `inputID.OnValueChangedAsObservable().Subscribe(s => buttonLogin.gameObject.SetActive(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Map` operator.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html

"transform the items emitted by an Observable by applying a function to each item"

Replace `Where` with `Map`, and inside the map operator, you'll be passed your `x` variable, and return the boolean from your `IsNullOrEmpty` check. That boolean will be passed in as a variable in your subscription which you can use directly in `setActive`.

Comment: Seems like you could just skip the `Where` and have `.Subscribe(x => buttonLogin.gameObject.SetActive(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` - or is this not as straight-forward as it looks?

Comment: That would also work but you lose out on sought-after reactive fanciness.

Comment: Fancy is... nice I guess.  But adding extra layers of complexity just so you can say "look how pretty this is" kinda sucks, doesn't it?  I'm far more interested in what works *best* than what looks pretty.  Except Expressions.  They're sexy.